# overalap div over image - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to overlap a div over an image which should also be responsive in nature.

Something like this.

> On mobile view the div's should stack up.

[image]

Here is something that I have been trying - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/24YxmZAYuf)

Comment: set the position of the dive to absolute

Comment: @Muhammad, it is set to absolute already

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways. The best solution may would be to define a background image. But negative margins do also work.

**CSS**

```
.overlay
{
    margin-top: -50px;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div><img class="img-responsive" src="http://img02.deviantart.net/0b78/i/2006/269/f/a/black_cats_by_black_cats.jpg"></div>

<div class="overlay">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: can you add a demo with this.

Comment: Why? You can Change it's behaviour the way you want by using jQuery for example.

Comment: If you don't wanna use Javascript, use z-index: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Comment: I have attached a demo in my question....can you alter that and show...my objective is a responsive design as well.

Comment: Well, If you want to work with a responsive grid, the image and the text columns should be a child of the same column. All you need is placing those elements in one responsive container.